# Run .sh in cygwin script from cmd

Tags: bash, cygwin, batch-file

I have a .bat script that calls some .exe to generate text files:

```
generate.bat:
...
ResGen main.txt Main.resources /str:c#
...
```

After that, I want to use vim's commandline search/replace on the generated file,
so I do this `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe searchreplace.sh`

```
searchreplace.sh:

echo "Hello from searchreplace.sh.."
vim Main.cs -c ":%s#internal#public#ge | update"
```

I get this error :

> searchreplace.sh: line 2: vim: command not found

I can use vim when I launch Cygwin64 from start menu, seems like a mistake in my scripts.. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Where is the vim executable stored? Is the directory part of your PATH?

Comment: No, it is not. Should it?

Comment: Just guessing whether it's a PATH-related issue. You should probably try the answer below first.

Answer (score 0):

Set the fill path to the vim like this:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\vim Main.cs -c ":%s#internal#public#ge | update"
```

or

```
/drives/c/cygwin64/bin/vim Main.cs -c ":%s#internal#public#ge | update"
```